# Group by based on a specific column and apply the function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am learning to apply self defined function to each of the group in data frame. Let say I have data frame as below:

```
A       B       C
1       4       3
1       5       4
1       2       10
2       7       2
2       4       4
2       6       6
```

I defined a simple function to get the length of column 'B' and the total of column 'C' followed by summation of the length and total for each group in column 'A' to generate column 'D'. Therefore I expect to have the following output:

```
A       D
1       20
2       15
```

I ran the code below and am not able to get what I want:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep="\t")
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  1  4   3
1  1  5   4
2  1  2  10
3  2  7   2
4  2  4   4
5  2  6   6
>>> 
>>> def someFunction(x, y):
...         length = len(x)
...         total = sum(y)
...         number = length + total
...         print(number)
... 
>>> f = lambda x: someFunction(x['B'], x['C'])
>>> output = df.groupby(['A']).apply(f)
20
20
15
>>> output
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
>>>
```

How do I get the desired output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This should the job :

```
import pandas as pd 

df= pd.DataFrame()

df['A']= [1,1,1,2,2,2]
df['B']= [4,3,2,7,4,6]
df['C']= [3,4,10,2,4,6]

def someFunction(data):

    return len(data['B'])+ sum(data['C'])

# apply to groupby 
df.groupby('A').apply(someFunction)

Output[1]:

A
1    20
2    15
dtype: int64
```

Remember to pass a `DataFrame` to the function, not `x` and `y` for more convenience in your code.

Comment: Do I just write `df.groupby('A').apply(someFunction)`, `df.groupby('A').apply(someFunction(df))` or `df.groupby('A').apply(someFunction())`? I don't seem to get it worked with all above.

Comment: This is the function I exactly want: `def someFunction(data):
        length = len(data['B'])
        if length == 1:
                return(data['B'])
        else:
                mx = data['B'][0]
                nx = data['C'][0]
                for i in range(1,length):
                        my = data['B'][i]
                        ny = data['C'][i]
                        nx = nx + ny
                        mx=(mx*nx+my*ny)/(nx+ny)
                        return(mx)`

Comment: I see your function. I suggest you do on two stages. You'll make more ocmplicated if you want to apply `groupby` and at the same apply the `somefucntion`. Perform the `groupby` first and then compute your `new column`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) for multiple aggregation functions, and then `sum` on `axis=1`:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'size', 'C':'sum'}).sum(1).reset_index(name='D')

   A   D
0  1  20
1  2  15
```

Comment: It is just a simple defined function I used as as an example here. In fact, I have a more complicated function which I wish to know how to apply to the groups.